# Neo4j odbc connection to qliksense

Tags: neo4j, cypher, odbc, qliksense

Can we execute cypher query through qliksense using ODBC connection?
Also, can anyone share the network graph used in qliksense which supports more nodes with arrow for indication and selection on nodes allowed?

I am trying to load with normal SQL select statements but need to execute a cypher query